# Angular CORS Error When Following Backend Redirect for OAuth2 Logout

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, oauth, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm working on a web application that uses Angular for the frontend and a Spring Boot backend. We have implemented OAuth2 login via Microsoft's identity platform. Logging in works fine, but I've run into an issue when trying to implement the logout.

Here's what happens

1. The user clicks 'Logout' in the Angular frontend.
2. An HTTP request issent to a /logout endpoint in my Spring Cloud Gateway.
3. The backend
   returns a 3XX redirect to Microsoft's logout URL, something like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/12345-345-450c-be26-e9df0d55c2fb/oauth2/v2.0/logout?id_token_hint=...&post_logout_redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000
```

The Angular client tries to follow this URL and then I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/...' (redirected from 'http://localhost:9000/logout') from origin 'http://localhost:9000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I don't understand why Angular is even trying to follow the redirect like a regular HTTP request. Isn't it supposed to be handled like a typical browser redirect?

Any idea what's going on here? And more importantly, how do I fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try to setup a proxy.conf.json at angular.json, proxying look for at official angular documentation (Building and serving Angular apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should observe the response of your POST request and set `window.location.href` with the value of the `location` header. [Something like](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/bff/frontend/src/app/user.service.ts):

```js
async logout() {
  return lastValueFrom(
    this.http.post(`/logout`, null, { observe: 'response' })
  ).then((response) => {
    const location = response.headers.get('Location');
    if (!!location) {
      window.location.href = location;
    }
  });
}
```

Like that the request origin will be Keycloak (setting the window location to an external URI "exits" your Angular app to "enter" a new website).

With an OpenID Provider following the [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) spec, this `logoutUri` you get from the gateway should point to your authorization server `end_session_endpoint`  and contain the following request params:

- `id_token_hint` of the user to logout from the authorization server
- `post_logout_redirect_uri` pointing back to your Angular app

But, to observe a `response`, the HTTP status must be in `2xx` range. The easiest way for that is probably to proxy an existing `ServerLogoutSuccessHandler` to change the response HTTP status. If your authorization server is fully compliant with [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) (I have no sufficient experience with `login.microsoftonline.com` to be sure, but from what I can see from the logout URI you provide, it seems to be), using Spring's `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler` as delegate is a good option. Sample taken from [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/tutorials/bff/backend/official/bff-official/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/dzone_oauth2_spring/official_bff/SecurityConf.java):

```java
static class AngularLogoutSucessHandler implements ServerLogoutSuccessHandler {
    private final OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler delegate;
        
    public AngularLogoutSucessHandler(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, String postLogoutRedirectUri) {
        this.delegate = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        this.delegate.setPostLogoutRedirectUri(postLogoutRedirectUri);
        }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> onLogoutSuccess(WebFilterExchange exchange, Authentication authentication) {
        return delegate.onLogoutSuccess(exchange, authentication).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
            exchange.getExchange().getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        }));
    }

}
```

```java
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain clientFilterCHain(
        ServerHttpSecurity http,
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        @Value("${post-logout-redirect-uri}") String postLogoutRedirectUri) {

    http.logout(logout -> {
        logout.logoutSuccessHandler(new AngularLogoutSucessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository, postLogoutRedirectUri));
    });

    ...

    return http.build()
}
```

The `post-logout-redirect-uri` is expected in properties (should point to your Angular app, with a path accessible to anonymous users).

Comment: This made a lot of sense but it does not work. The backend returns 302 and as I found out the browser kicks in before the SPA can take any action. So the resp is just an error which does not have the location header anymore

Comment: Oups, forgot to mention that you should change the status to something in 2xx field. That's what I do in [this tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/034835a3ce89a4b669f5186bdd04be6772a47ea1/samples/tutorials/bff/gateway/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/samples/bff/gateway/GatewayController.java#L84) (which does exactly what you are looking for). Also, with Keycloak, I'm configuring an `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler` in gateway security (if you're not doing it with Keycloak, you should)

Comment: Thank you ch4mp you are the best! You helped me out so much

Comment: @JangoCG I just found a more elegant way to change the HTTP status of the response to the POST request to `/logout`: proxy an existing `ServerLogoutSucessHandler`. This removes the need to provide by yourself a controller endpoint to handle logout. See my updated answer (or tutorials).